# Node dbus-native - Passing Passphrase while connecting to WiFi service using connMan

Tags: javascript, node.js, wifi, dbus, connman

Hi I have been having this problem for the last couple of days, while trying to connect to a protected WiFi network using dbus. So the code I have developed so far is:

**Register Agent**

```
var dbus = require('dbus-native');
var bus = dbus.systemBus();
bus.invoke({
        destination: 'net.connman',
        path: '/',
        'interface': 'net.connman.Manager',
        member: 'RegisterAgent',
        type: dbus.messageType.methodCall,
        signature: 'o',
        body: [
                '/test/agent'
        ]
}, function(error, response) {
        if (error) {
                console.error('Error', error);
                //process.exit(1);
        } else {
                console.info('Success', response);
               // process.exit(0);
        }
});
```

**Output**

```
> Success
```

**Scan Wifi**

```
var dbus = require('dbus-native');
var bus = dbus.systemBus();
bus.invoke({
        destination: 'net.connman',
        path: '/net/connman/technology/wifi',
        'interface': 'net.connman.Technology',
        member: 'Scan',
        type: dbus.messageType.methodCall,
}, function(error, response) {
        if (error) {
                console.error('Error', error);
                //process.exit(1);
        } else {
                console.info('Success', response);
                //process.exit(0);
        }
});
```

**Output**

```
> Success
```

**Connect to WiFi Service**

```
var dbus = require('dbus-native');
var bus = dbus.systemBus();
bus.invoke({
        destination: 'net.connman',
        path: '/net/connman/service/wifi_00e04c81923e_4469676957494649_managed_psk',
        'interface': 'net.connman.Service',
        member: 'Connect',
        type: dbus.messageType.methodCall,
}, function(error, response) {
        if (error) {
                console.error('Error', error);
                //process.exit(1);
        } else {
                console.info('Success', response);
                //process.exit(0);
        }
});
```

**Output**

```
> Error ['Invalid Arguments']
```

**Output fropm connMan logs**

> connmand[1899]: src/agent.c:agent_receive_message() agent 0x55640fe8
>   req 0x55644378
>
> connmand[1899]: src/service.c:request_input_cb() RequestInput return,
>   0x55649ad0
>
> connmand[1899]:src/service.c:request_input_cb()error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownService
>
> connmand[1899]: src/service.c:__connman_service_return_error() service
>   0x55649ad0 error 22 user_data (nil)
>
> connmand[1899]: src/service.c:__connman_service_set_hidden_data()
>   service 0x55649ad0 pending (nil)
>
> connmand[1899]: src/service.c:service_save() service 0x55649ad0 new 1
>
> connmand[1899]: src/connection.c:update_order()
>
> connmand[1899]: src/service.c:__connman_service_get_order() service
>   0x55640a08 name Wired order 1 split 0
>
> connmand[1899]: src/connection.c:find_default_gateway() default
>   0x5563b250 order 1
>
> connmand[1899]: src/connection.c:__connman_connection_update_gateway()
>   default 0x5563b250
>
> connmand[1899]: src/service.c:connman_service_unref_debug() 0x55649ad0
>   ref 1 by src/service.c:6945:agent_context_unref()

So basically, I would greatly appreciate it if someone could show me how to pass back the user data containing the passphrase for the WiFi network.

Any help would be greatly appreciated? (connMan version 1.20)

Thanks

Comment: looks like you need to register agent first: https://pythonhosted.org/pyconnman/demo.html#setting-up-an-agent-to-connect-to-new-network-services

Comment: also double check path is spelled correctly - connmand[1899]:src/service.c:request_input_cb()error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownService is suspicious

Comment: check out https://github.com/cfsghost/jsdx-connman it uses dbus instead of dbus-native but should be a good start anyway

Comment: oops, you already registering agent. Ok, here is the problem: agent is your service that handles requests _from_ connman. You need to create dbus service at your connection name + agent path ( which is "/" in your case )

Comment: Hi Andrey, thank you for your helpful comments could you elaborate a little bit more on the solution maybe provide a code example so i fully understand?

Comment: Hi! I'll try to post example (unfortunately, I only have connman in virtualbox and it's tricky to get virtualized wifi)

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get dbus-native to work.

My solution was to create a wifi.config file in /lib/connman/ which contains the passphrase for each service:

**wifi.config example**

```
[service_wifi_00e04c819295_4469679972434649_managed_psk] 
Type = wifi
Security = wpa2 
Name = [service_] 
Type = wifi 
Security = wpa2 
Name = WiFiAP
Passphrase = 12345
```

Then simply used dbus-native to connect to the WiFi service:

**Connect**

```
var dbus = require('dbus-native');
var bus = dbus.systemBus();
bus.invoke({
        destination: 'net.connman',
        path: '/net/connman/service/wifi_48022aca514f_4469676957494649_managed_psk',
        'interface': 'net.connman.Service',
        member: 'Connect',
        type: dbus.messageType.methodCall,
}, function(error, response) {
        if (error) {
                console.error('Error', error);
                //process.exit(1);
        } else {
                console.info('Success', response);
                //process.exit(0);
        }
});
```